# Is it possible to use existing GCM senderId and API key for GCM To APNS push notification?

Tags: google-cloud-messaging, apple-push-notifications

I have existing project sending the push notification to Android client app.

Now there is a requirement we need to send push to APNS using GCM service.

So is it possible to use same senderId and API key of existing project for APNS push?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible!

Sending downstream messages to Android or iOS are just HTTP or XMPP requests or stanzas.

You do need to set-up APNs and upload the resulting p12 so GCM can send messages to the iOS device. But as far as your message sender is concerned there is no distinction other than message format, some fields work on Android some on iOS and some on both.

See details of [adding support for iOS](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/ios/client).

So to be clear you can use an existing Google Developer project to send GCM messages to iOS.